# Problems with overriding functions

Tags: c++, class, void, unreal-engine4

Im making FPS game and right now adding bots. I got problems with one function that shows overriden problem. Problem is with void - Possess.

I haven't tryed this.

```
/****
*this is .h file
*****/
 #pragma once

 #include "CoreMinimal.h"

 #include "AIController.h"

 #include "Engine.h"

 #include "AI_Controller.generated.h"


UCLASS()

class TEST_API AAI_Controller : public AAIController
{

GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    AAI_Controller();

        virtual void BeginPlay() override;

        virtual void Possess(APawn* Pawn) override;

        virtual void Tick(float DeltaSeconds) override;

        virtual FRotator GetControlRotation() const override;

        UFUNCTION()
            void OnPawnDetected(const TArray<AActor*> &DetectedPawns);

        UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = AI)
            float AISightRadius = 500.0f;

        UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = AI)
            float AISightAge = 5.0f;

        UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = AI)
            float AILoseSightRadius = AISightRadius + 50.0f;

        UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = AI)
            float AIFieldOfView = 90.0f;

        UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = AI)
            class UAISenseConfig_Sight* SightConfig;

};
```

I expected void Possess to work without giving any errors, because i dont see anything wrong in my code and i think it should work. it shows this error - 
'AController::Possess': function declared as 'final' cannot be overridden by 'AAI_Controller::Possess'

i will be thankful , if someone could explain what happened and how to fix this.

Comment: The error explains everything. The base class function is declared as final, that means you cannot override it. You need to remove the final, or if you cannot, find another way to do what you want to do.

Comment: But how do i remove the final?

Comment: I would guess you don't. There must be another way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Still, thanks for helping. I have to finish this code part this week but im stuck on this error... I hope someone can help out with this

Comment: Who wrote the `AAIController` class?

Comment: Typos?  "AAI_Controller::Possess(..)"  (with 'override')    "AAIController::Posses(...) (not shown)'?   "AController::Possess(..)" (in error msg?) – 3  class names?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the function is final is because it is a deprecated function as of Unreal Engine v4.22.  I wouldn't advise modifying it, or even using it at all.  Instead use OnPossess and OnUnpossess and everything should work fine.

```
virtual void OnPossess(APawn* InPawn) override;
virtual void OnUnPossess() override;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the declaration of `AController::Possess()` has been declared final so the compiler prevents you from overriding the function in `AAI_Controller`.

You can either go to where the class `AController` is declared and remove the `final` keyword, something like:
`virtual void Possess(APawn* pawn) final` to `virtual void Possess(APawn* pawn)` and that will remove the error. You should be careful doing this though, if you didn't write the base class, there is probably a good reason the function was declared final in the first place

Or if you can't do that and you can get away with changing the function signature, just create your own that function isn't an override of the base member function.